# Channel hangs, probably not closing at the right place

Tags: go, hash, path, filesystems, checksum

I'm trying to learn Go while writing a small program. The program should parse a PATH recursivelys as efficient and fast as possible and output the full filename (with the path included) and the sha256 file hash of the file.

If the file hashing generates fails, I wanna keep the error and add it to the string (at the hash position).

The result should return a string on the console like:
fileXYZ||hash

Unfortunately, the programs hangs at some point. I guess some of my channels are not closing properly and waiting indefinitely for input. I've been trying for quite some time to fix the problem, but without success.

Does anyone have an idea why the output hangs? Many many thx in advance, any input/advice for a Go newcomer is welcome too ;-).

(I wrote separate functions as I wanna add additional features after having fixed this issue.)

Thanks a lot!
Didier

Here is the code:

```
import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    pathParam := flag.String("path", ".", "Enter Filesystem Path to list folders")
    flag.Parse()
    start := time.Now()
    run(*pathParam)
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    log.Printf("Time elapsed: %v", elapsed)
}

func run(path string) {
    chashes := make(chan string, 50)
    cfiles := make(chan string)

    go func() {
        readfs(path, cfiles)
        defer close(cfiles)
    }()
    go func() {
        generateHash(cfiles, chashes)
    }()
    defer close(chashes)
    for hash := range chashes {
        fmt.Println(hash)
    }
}

func readfs(path string, cfiles chan string) {
    files, err := os.ReadDir(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    for _, file := range files {
        filename := filepath.Join(path, file.Name())
        if file.IsDir() {
            readfs(filename, cfiles)
            continue
        } else {
            cfiles <- filename
        }
    }
}

func generateHash(cfiles chan string, chashes chan string) {
    for filename := range cfiles {
        go func(filename string) {
            var checksum string
            var oError bool = false
            file, err := os.Open(filename)
            if err != nil {
                oError = true
                errorMsg := "ERROR: " + err.Error()
                log.Println(errorMsg)
                checksum = errorMsg
            }
            defer file.Close()

            if !oError {
                hash := sha256.New()
                if _, err := io.Copy(hash, file); err != nil {
                    errorMsg := "ERROR: " + err.Error()
                    log.Println(errorMsg)
                    checksum = errorMsg
                }
                if len(checksum) == 0 {
                    checksum = hex.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil))
                }
            }
            chashes <- filename + "||" + checksum
        }(filename)
    } //for files
}
```

Comment: You are making a channel of size 50. Are you sure that there are 50 hashes because the for loop in `run` will read the channel 50 times.

Comment: Thx for replying. No as I don't how many files I will have. It tested so much different code ;-) ... I removed the 50 in the channel, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Receiving to channel is a blocking call and if you don't know know the numbers of files to process in the folder then either you will end up exiting the program before processing all the files or you will end up in a deadlock waiting for the hashes to process from the channel. You can use select and make one quit channel when you will process all the files and signal the program to exit when need.
Give [this](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/5) a read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following loop hangs because `chashes` is not closed.

```
for hash := range chashes {
    fmt.Println(hash)
}
```

Fix by closing `chashes` after all the hashers are completed.  Use a sync.WaitGroup to wait for the hashers to complete.

```
func generateHash(cfiles chan string, chashes chan string) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for filename := range cfiles {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(filename string) {
            defer wg.Done()
            var checksum string
            var oError bool = false
            file, err := os.Open(filename)
            if err != nil {
                oError = true
                errorMsg := "ERROR: " + err.Error()
                log.Println(errorMsg)
                checksum = errorMsg
            }
            defer file.Close()

            if !oError {
                hash := sha256.New()
                if _, err := io.Copy(hash, file); err != nil {
                    errorMsg := "ERROR: " + err.Error()
                    log.Println(errorMsg)
                    checksum = errorMsg
                }
                if len(checksum) == 0 {
                    checksum = hex.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil))
                }
            }
            chashes <- filename + "||" + checksum
        }(filename)
    } //for files

    // Wait for the hashers to complete.
    wg.Wait()

    // Close the channel to cause main() to break
    // out of for range on chashes.
    close(chashes)
}
```

Remove `defer close(chashes)` from `run()`.

[Run an example on the Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/0oHPyr5dpW1).